# Hint icon disappear in searchview

Tags: android

when I search something in search view then the hint icon is disappeared I want that hint icon while searching something

[image]

```
   SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    EditText searchEditText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    searchEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.search, null,null, null);
```

I tried to add let drawable in Edittext

Comment: You should add some code what you have done..

Comment: code added @RishilP.

Comment: Take a look at this -  http://nlopez.io/how-to-style-the-actionbar-searchview-programmatically/

Comment: i tried that but didn't work @matinsayyad

Answer (score 0):

Hope so this will help Change your searchView as:

add this to your searchView `app:iconifiedByDefault="false"`

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
           app:iconifiedByDefault="false"/>
```